# How to add value to an array inside of a hash with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

```
contacts_r = File.open("user_contacts.txt", "r")

user_contacts = []
contacts_r.readlines.each { |line|
  user_contacts << line.chomp
}

$c = Hash[user_contacts.map { |x| ["$#{x}_called", Array.new] } ]
```

When I try to add info in the desired array...

```
$c["#{name}_called"] << 1
```

I get a undefined method `'<<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

when I use..

```
puts $c
```

the output looks like

```
{"$robert_called"=>[]}
```

I'm trying to make it look like

```
{"$robert_called"=>[1]}
```

Comment: What is `name`? If it's not `"robert"`, the error is obvious. Your code otherwise looks okay. (I'd probably contract the whole thing into `user_contacts = File.read(filename).lines.map(&:chomp)` or the lazier `user_contacts = File.open(filename) { |f| f.each_line.map(&:chomp) }`, and use a hash with a default proc (`c = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] }`) so I don't have to initialise it at all... Also, beware global variables, they have a nasty habit of biting you in the behind.

Comment: by `"#{name}"` i just meant thats where the namesgo...its no actualy part of the code :\ @Amadan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to prepend `$`.

```
$c["$#{name}_called"] << 1
```

Comment: ...and `$[k] => nil` (i.e., the value of key `k` is `nil`) if the hash does not have a key `k`, so `$c[k] << 1` becomes `nil << 1`. `nil` is the one and only instance of [NilClass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/NilClass.html). `NilClass` has no instance method `:<<`, which means that `nil` has no method `:<<`. That's precisely what the error message is telling you. Study error messages carefully. Often they pinpoint the problem.

Comment: your right, I forgot to put the $ in the array name. And i'm still considerably new (not even a year) so I'll pay more attention to what the errors are saying, thanks. :)